# Best position for play Power Chords standing

Tags: guitar, chords, electric-guitar

I usually play standing and the guitar body is somewhere around my belt. For power chords, I use the index finger and pinky, but some chords I play with the ring one.

In every tutorial, teachers show power chords this way:

[image]

But I just can't play this way **standing**: I feel no control if the neck doesn't lay on my palm or pinky finger. I like moving a lot while playing. There're two positions is ok for me, but I don't know is they ok and which is better:

1. It allows me to keep the wrist straight. Thumb over the neck. The neck lays on palm - [imgur-link-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27RYc.jpg)
2. The wrist is bend. The thumb is above the neck. The neck lays on the pinky finger - [imgur-link-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awCK2.jpg)

I like my wrist to be straight and I like when the neck lays on the palm or pinky finger.
**Should I avoid this contact?**
I fell that this allows me to control the guitar better while jumping around with it.

Also: Is it ok to mute **A** and top **E** strings with my middle finger simultaneously while I’m playing **F5** chord? Or should I better mute **A** string with the middle finger and **E** string with my thumb(guess it depends on the thumb position)?

I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Looking at the 'proper' picture, I can't even see how a 'power chord' can be played. The fingers don't even reach the low strings.

Comment: Try posting a pic or 2 of yourself playing, so we can see how you stand etc.

Comment: @ggcg 
Updated. Posted new pic playing stand.  

1.  The wrist is straight. Thumb over the neck. The neck lays on palm -  [imgur-link-1](https://imgur.com/a/tzbJq5O)  

2. The wrist is bend. The thumb is behind the neck. The neck lays on the pinky finger -    [imgur-link-2](https://imgur.com/a/LQKBnUb)

Comment: Having looked at the pics I'd say that you are not as low as Jimmy Page but getting there.  This will put strain on you wrist eventually causing pain.  One option is to angle the neck more, another is grip the neck with the thumb over (not preferred), and finally make the strap shorter.

Comment: @ggcg
Already made the strap shorter. Finally, I decide the 'coolness' factor is not worth it. At least at my level of playing.
Thank you! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, coolness.  I was a big Jimmy Page poser in my teens.  A serious professional musician now I NEVER play with the guitar that low (Unless I'm using a violin bow).  I opt for the Steve Howe look (also a great and cool player).

Comment: @ggcg
I'll definitely take a look at him.
I like Tom Morello, who keeps the guitar high, but cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the guitar high like Steve Howe that should not be a problem.  But a lot of rock guitarists put the guitar low, like Jimmy Page.  If you have the guitar this low proper hand posture is impossible.  You could try angling the guitar so the head of the neck comes up to your chest level.  This might allow you to play power chords in the lower positions the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I angle the head up. It really helps!

Comment: @Zayac Press the up-vote button if you think the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried first, playing the power chords whilst sitting down, and if it makes a difference?  I recommend using a strap on your guitar, even if you're sitting down as it positions your guitar well (and secures it too!).

Also as with learning any new chords, practice over time, can help.  Keep trying to adjust your hand as you play, over time, you will learn which position suits best.